# USING Ellucian Banner API

Tags: api, banner, ellucian-banner

I'm attempting to use a Banner API Call.
per the documentation the create call looks like this.

```
PROCEDURE p_create(
    p_pidm                      gorimmu.gorimmu_pidm%TYPE,
    p_immu_code                 gorimmu.gorimmu_immu_code%TYPE,
    p_seq_no                    gorimmu.gorimmu_seq_no%TYPE,
    p_user_id                   gorimmu.gorimmu_user_id%TYPE DEFAULT gb_common.f_sct_user,
    p_immu_date                 gorimmu.gorimmu_immu_date%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_imst_code                 gorimmu.gorimmu_imst_code%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_comment                   gorimmu.gorimmu_comment%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_data_origin               gorimmu.gorimmu_data_origin%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_seq_no_out            OUT gorimmu.gorimmu_seq_no%TYPE,
    p_rowid_out             OUT gb_common.internal_record_id_type);
```

I'm not sure how to use the last two fields that have OUT.
I've used other API calls..but none of them used an OUT.

any help is appreciated..banner documentation not helpful

Answer (score 0):

That just means you must provide a parameter for the API call to populate. So define two variables to pass in such as:
l_seq_no_out gorimmu.gorimmu_seq_no%TYPE;
l_rowid_out  gb_common.internal_record_id_type;
Then just pass those as the last two parameters to the p_create call.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).